# Wordpress custom sub template, Template within template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a custom post type defined in Wordpress. Please look at the following image(not my work just used for reference):

[image]

For each of the posts within the custom post type I would like to define 3 sub templates that can be chosen from within the WP admin:- Content left, Content centre, Content right. When they are rendered out within the loop (not single page) the output would be similar to the above image.

Can this be done in Wordpress? If it can please can you help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to give the three parts content. Custom fields can only handle plain text so you can also use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to add a ritch .